# How to debug Android's Unable to resume activity error?

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I'm getting an error in main thread:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {...}:
java.lang.NullPointerException`
```

However, there is no user code in the stack trace:

```
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2841)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm not sure where this is originating from as I'm just hitting the `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` method. All I know is that it's a null pointer exception. I've changed *many* things since the last build, so I have no idea where this is thrown. How can I debug this error when there's no user code? I've got nothing that can throw in `onResume` either:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    instance = this;
    super.onResume();
}
```

The `onResume` method is being hit, and is executed to the end without an exception. How do I debug the error?

Comment: if you are using the `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler `, I suggest you should print the stacktrace with these codes  `StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString(); Log.d(TAG,exceptionAsString)`. So you can get more detail information about exception.

Comment: @buptcoder and how do you think I've pasted the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found out the solution: somewhere around refactoring, Android Studio stupidly renamed a completely unrelated view's ID in another file just because it happened to have the same common name ("listView") with the object that I was renaming.

Anyway, here is how I resolved it:

- I've clicked `View Breakpoints...` from the menu.
- I've added a `Java Exception Breakpoint`.
- I've set the exception's class to `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
- I've started debugging.

I've hit some inner exceptions too, but I just ignored them and clicked next, then after a few clicks, I was right on the error. So sad that Android Studio doesn't provide an intuitive way to debug this kind of common errors (which was ironically caused by Android Studio itself).

Do not forget to turn off exception breakpoints after the issue is solved as it tends to break on *every* null pointer exception, including those are thrown inside the framework and caught gracefully.